# How to write date and time to a log file on the same line using batch

Tags: batch-file, logfile

I'm currently making a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to write the date and time to a [logfile](/questions/tagged/logfile), but I can't find out how to keep the info on the same line of the `.log`.

```
REM Clear the screen
REM ------------------------------------------------------
cls


date /T >> C:\\myTemp\devTracker.log 
time /T >> C:\\myTemp\devTracker.log 


ECHO Starting Microsoft Visual Studio...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the current date and time from a batch file using the predefined `%date%` and `%time%` variables without calling `date.exe` or `time.exe`. Just write them directly to the logfile using `echo`.

```
echo %date% %time% >> C:\mytemp\devtracker.log
```